# Retrieving website content and returning it in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, proxy

I have two servers. One is a private server and I don't want users to have direct access to it, and the other one is the server that public does have access to.
I can access my private server by URL like: http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/

What i want to do is create some kind of "proxy", only to work with my private server. My idea is to go to: http://www.domain.com/server/path/here/something
This page should show me the content of http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/path/here/something

I have this working, but the only way I could make it work was to return the content as a string, and then the browser would interpret the HTML.
This works fine for pages that return HTML content, but it doesn't work (of course) if I want to access a .gif or any kind of file directly.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
    public string Index(string url)
    {
        string uri = "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/" + url;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string resultado = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

        return resultado;
    }
```

How can I change my code so that it works for any file ?

Comment: can't you use a real proxy to achieve this??

Comment: I don't know if there's a better way of doing it.
I just want to get the content from my private server (by using the URL I explained before), and show it on my public server.

Comment: Can the public server access the files on the private one directly?  Or does it have to be a web request?

Comment: It can't access them directly. It needs to be a web request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the response content type and do what you need based on that.
You'll need to change your action to return `ActionResult` instead of string.

```
if(response.ContentType.Equals("text/html"))
{
 //show html stuff
 return Content(resultado);

}
else if(response.ContentType.Contains("image/"))
{

   var ms = new MemoryStream();
    responseStream.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms);

    var imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
  return File(imageBytes, response.ContentType);
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I'm returning a string..
Should I return another type instead?

Comment: @FedeLerner that depends. Where exactly are you returning the string? who/what is the consumer of this return type?

Comment: Well, it's an ASP.NET MVC 4 (4.0 .NET Framework) application so the string gets returned to the client, the Index function you see in my question is on the Controller. I directly return the string of responseStream.ReadToEnd() and that's the way the browser client gets the HTML and interprets it.. I guess this isn't the best way to do this, but it's the only way I got to make it work (unfortunately, limiting it to only HTML).

Comment: @FedeLerner it doesn't really limit it in any way. whatever images are in the html will get rendered if they have absolute urls.

Comment: The thing is that it's accessing an image directly, so the result is: GIF89a� �_(etc etc..)

Comment: @FedeLerner in that scenario you can let your action return an ActionResult (so it can either return a Content(string) or a FileResult(byte[]). Do they test to see what ContentType then return appropriate content. i've updated my answer

Comment: I've set "ActionResult" as the method type. What should I return? Trying to return Content(resultado) gives the same result as before. Content(responseStream) throws error as it can't accept that parameter. I can't also return responseStream as it can't convert StreamReader to ActionResult..

Comment: @FedeLerner Take a look at my answer. i've modified it to fit your context, and you'll notice it uses YOUR variables. i check the content type and return either a Content(string) or a FileResult (which is a subclass of ActionResult)

Comment: Thanks, we're much closer now.. It's returning an image but it's of 0 bytes. I've checked and it does enter the "image/gif" if statement.

Comment: @FedeLerner Not sure why it is returning an image if it didnt' enter that IF block. maybe we should change the IF statement to check for "image" prefix in the content type. i've modified my answer. please only return an image from inside the if block.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write a system which reads your html or images from resultado and do something according to that PLUS you need to control your Url as well.